# Call to a member function on null, phone validation service

Tags: php, symfony

PHP with Symfony framework:

First of all before the context:

My input form is being built by form builder. Nothing is wrong there. So that is not the problem

I am making a sms validator system. I have a controller, and 2 services(validatorservice, smsapi(for api call)) Now my validatorservice looks like this:

```
class ValidatorService
{
public function validate($telefoonnummer)
{

    $pregpatternNL = '(^\+[0-9]{2}|^\+[0-9]{2}\(0\)|^\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10}$)';

    if (!preg_match($pregpatternNL, $telefoonnummer)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Then my homecontroller:

```
use App\Service\ValidatorService;
class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /** @var SmsApi */
private $smsApi;
/** @var validatorService */
private $validatorService;

public function __construct1(SmsApi $smsApi, Validatorservice 
$validatorService)
{
    $this->smsApi = $smsApi;
    $this->validatorService = $validatorService;
}

/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(
        SmsLogFormType::class,
        new SmsLog(),
        [
            'method' => 'post',
        ]
    );

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var SmsLog $smslog */
        $formData = $form->getData();

    try {
        $telefoonnummer = $formData->getTel();
        $telefoonnummer = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $telefoonnummer);
        $validatorservices = $this->validatorService- 
        >validate($telefoonnummer);
            if ($validatorserviceres === false) {
                $this->addFlash(
                    'notice',
                    'telefoonnummer onjuist formaat'
                );
                exit;
            } else {
    blablabla
    }
```

Now whatever i try i get the error :

> Call to a member function validate() on null

At first i thought maybe its something with the `constructor` names, but found online that that doesn't matter at all (also i didn't receive any code errors there)

Then i tried adding echo's to the if statement in my service. Maybe return true or false is seen as `null` but this doesn't work either.

Comment: You could try dump the service before calling the method. Are your constructors working ? I didnt know you could define multiple and symfony can handle the DI.
That would at least match your error since the class variable would still be null.
Edit: Btw, why are you not using the validation directly in your form ?

Comment: @WhiteRabbit php.net shows that it is possible. I can't come up with anything to fix this  in any other way

Comment: PHP does not support multiple constructors and yes the name does very much matter.  You are misreading something or someone is playing a joke on you.  Just use one constructor with two arguments.  PHP is not a big fan of polymorphism.

Comment: I did a fast test in my application, my services are not autowired if i try it "your" way. Why are you not using the standart __construct() method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because of the number of arguments per constructor. If you define multiple constructors for a class, they should have different argument counts.

What you could do instead is to check whether or not the object you received is part of the wanted class/classes.
Or create static functions that instatiate the class with different object types.

---

**EDIT**
Use the default autowiring mechanisms:

```
private $smsApi;
private $validatorService;

public function __construct(SmsApi $smsApi, ValidatorService $validatorService)
{
    $this->smsApi = $smsApi;
    $this->validatorService = $validatorService;
}
```

Comment: Ah okay i dont really know about that first one. Anyway both constructors just require 1 parameter...

Comment: @JornBarkhof Well I guess then it's not possible to achive your goal with multiple constructors. Use a single one instead and type check for your classes. PHP is dynamic and can't handle your situation as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks, i have now made it into 1 constructor. But i am still getting the same error

Comment: Fixed it, Cache cleared and it now works, Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

It should work as intended if you change your Code to this :

```
/** @var SmsApi */
private $smsApi;

private $validatorService;

public function __construct(SmsApi $smsApi, ValidatorService $validatorService)
{
    $this->validatorService = $validatorService;
    $this->smsApi = $smsApi;
}
```

Comment: Yea thanks i already came up with that just 1 minute ago, Still getting the same error

Comment: Try clear the local cache and check if your class is registered as service :
php bin/console debug:container  or debug:autowiring
You should find an entry with the namespace of your class

Answer (score 1):

__construct1 and __construct2 are not native functions of php, so when the class is loaded, the constructors are not invoking and validatorService/smsApi are not being set (so they are null). The native function is called __construct.

```
/** @var SmsApi */
private $smsApi;
private $validatorService;

public function __construct(SmsApi $smsApi, ValidatorService $validatorService)
{
    $this->smsApi = $smsApi;
    $this->validatorService = $validatorService;
}
```

Or if doest not work, inject the services as arg in

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
```

so...

```
public function indexAction(Request $request,SmsApi $smsApi, ValidatorService $validatorService)
```

and `use $validatorService->validate();`